# How long mopub ad unit takes to warm up?

Tags: android, mopub

I'm using successfully MoPub displaying ads correclty. I created a new Ad Unit in the MoPub publisher console, I changed the current id with the new id but no ads are displayed anymore.
In the logcat I see the following message:

```
Ad Unit (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) is still warming up. Please try again in a few minutes.
```

I waited for 8 hours but still get no ads. What's I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I started receiving ads. It seems that up to 2 days are needed to warm up ad-units. Also posted a request on the mopub forum without having got any response (https://groups.google.com/a/mopub.com/forum/#!category-topic/mopub-users/technical-integration/71iV6IFEFJ0)

Comment: I'm running almost three weeks here. Customer support (both the support and policy lines) avoided my questions and cut off contact after about two emails. Ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

> ad unit still warming up is something you'd see in an ad unit that doesn't receive a lot of traffic. If you try again in a few minutes/make a few more requests, the ad unit should respond with an ad.